# Android 8.0 issue for File share through other app (Email,Whatsapp etc..)

Tags: android, uri, android-contentprovider, android-8.0-oreo, fileshare

I have .wav files in my internal storage.
using my android app I want to share that files using the supported app.

```
ArrayList<Uri> files = new ArrayList<Uri>(); 
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
share.setType("audio/x-wav");
share.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, files);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share"));
```

it is working up to android version 7 but in android 8.0 this code is not working.
Can anyone suggest what needs to change?

here my file is present in internla storeage not in app(package) folder